# Does org.json.JSONObject break Object.equals() contract?

Tags: java, android, json

With [JSONObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) you can make:

```
JSONObject.NULL.equals(null); //returns true
```

`JSONObject.NULL` breaks `Object.equals()` contract, at least it seems like it does, since

> For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false

The fact that this class is so widely used and supported makes me think that there is no violation for some reason, is there?

Comment: Since the JsonObject is a container, I don't feel this is a really a violation of the contract, with this kind of object the equals is use to check the contained data. So if you can't test if a "Null Json Instance" is null, you are going to have some problems ;)

Comment: Where is the above code ? http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib/2.4/net/sf/json/JSONObject.java#JSONObject.equals%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: @ViswanathLekshmanan this is net.sf.json.JSONObject, not org.json.JSONObject

Comment: @Orlangure It violates the contract. See answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It clearly violates the Object.equals()** since

- JSONObject.NULL is not **null** but a new `Object()`
- Return value is `true` instead of `false`

`JSONObject.NULL` from source looks like below & the value is not null.

```
public static final Object NULL = new Object() {

    @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o == this || o == null; // API specifies this broken equals implementation
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return "null";
    }

};
```

`equals()` from `Object` looks like

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return this == o;
}
```

The additional comparison of **o == null** in `JSONObject.NULL` `equals()` method will always return `true` if we pass **null**. Hence

```
JSONObject.NULL.equals(null); //Will return true
```

Answer (score 2):

The [NULL-Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) is a pattern that is used to avoid checks like `if(object == null)`.
It is the same thing here. The `NULL` is just a name. But what do you really have is not actually `null` (null-reference) but an object that gives a default-behavior (not-null reference).